# JAI: ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to use JAI to process a TIF. I should point out that, prior to today, it was working fine. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong, and the part of the code the exception is coming from is not one that I changed.

Anyway, The exception cause is a ClassCastException coming from within one of the core JAI classes. Which makes absolutely no sense, but it's happening.

Here's the stack trace and the code. Any advice would be great. I'm totally lost on this one. Truly hate JAI, but Commons Imaging is even worse, so I guess I'm stuck with it.

> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.readTiffImageFromSeekableStream(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:486)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.readTiffImageFromFile(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:425)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.bufferImageFromFile(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:394)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.getImageFromFile(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:277)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.overlayImageItem(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:252)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.overlayImagesOnPDF(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:115)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.modules.other.pdfoverlay.PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.processData(PDFMultiOverlayProcessor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.transact.stages.ProcessorStage.process(ProcessorStage.java:44)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.transact.StageHandler.process(StageHandler.java:99)
>     at
>   com.pilotfish.eip.transact.Transaction.runStage(Transaction.java:115)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.media.jai.imageioimpl.ImageReadWriteSpi cannot be cast to
>   javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi  at
>   javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.registerServices(OperationRegistry.java:2047)
>     at
>   javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.registerServices(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:612)
>     at
>   javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:365)
>     at javax.media.jai.JAI.(JAI.java:560)   ... 14 more

```
private BufferedImage readTiffImageFromSeekableStream(SeekableStream seekStream){
        TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();
        decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
        ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
        params.add(seekStream);
        RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
        return image1.getAsBufferedImage();
    }
```

The line the exception gets thrown from is the next to last: RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);

Help. Please. So damn lost here, this library has just been one giant headache from day one, but I don't know of any better alternative and I need this thing to just work again. I've spent the last two hours trying to figure this out, and have gotten absolutely nowhere.

Comment: I have the same piece of code (excluding getAsBuffered()) so its time to put it all on the screen -  or its time to clean up the computer - maybe you found the bug

Comment: Haven't found it yet. I bypassed it briefly by using ImageIO.read(...), and none of this other stuff. That worked on my machine, but my coworker's machine he can't get it working. I hate JAI with a passion, I'm right now begging for us to not have to use TIFF.

Comment: Maybe open a question that details what happened on your coworkers machine. (you will need jai_imageio.jar) Alternatively, give twelvemonkeys a try. (Please don't start a rant on his site if it doesn't work, I really like the guy)